# Заполнение progressBar по часовой стрелке

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, android-drawable

У меня есть `ProgressBar`:

**layout.xml**

```
<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar_result_learn"
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progregress_bar_drawable"
android:rotation="270" />
```

**proress_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="3.8sp">

            <solid android:color="@color/colorBackgroundGrey" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        >
        <clip>
            <shape
                android:innerRadiusRatio="2.3"
                android:shape="ring"
                android:thickness="3.8sp">

                <solid android:color="@color/green" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Во время анимации прогресса прогресс заполняет его как бы ленейно хоть и по кругу. а я хочу что  бы заполнение происходило типа как а с 12 часов до 12  по часовой стрелке.

Вот то как это у меня получается, прогресс идет и слева и справа,  как сделать так что  бы он шел в нужном мне направлении

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте [HoloCircularProgressBar](https://github.com/passsy/android-HoloCircularProgressBar),
Вот еще: [Circle-Progress-View](https://github.com/jakob-grabner/Circle-Progress-View)

Comment: @TITAN меня интересует как это можно сделать стандартными способами, без подключения библиотек!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот простое решение

**CircleProgressBar.java**

```
public class CircleProgressBar extends View {


    /**
     * ProgressBar's line thickness
     */
    private float strokeWidth = 4;
    private float progress = 0;
    private int min = 0;
    private int max = 100;
    /**
     * Start the progress at 12 o'clock
     */
    private int startAngle = -90;
    private int color = Color.DKGRAY;
    private RectF rectF;
    private Paint backgroundPaint;
    private Paint foregroundPaint;

    /**Animation duration */
    private int animDuration = 5000;

    public float getStrokeWidth() {
        return strokeWidth;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth) {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        backgroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        foregroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();//Because it should recalculate its bounds
    }

    public float getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(float progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        backgroundPaint.setColor(adjustAlpha(color, 0.3f));
        foregroundPaint.setColor(color);
        invalidate();
        requestLayout();
    }

    public int getAnimDuration() {
        return animDuration;
    }

    public void setAnimDuration(int animDuration) {
        this.animDuration = animDuration;
    }

    public CircleProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        rectF = new RectF();
        TypedArray typedArray = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.CircleProgressBar,
                0, 0);
        //Reading values from the XML layout
        try {
            strokeWidth = typedArray.getDimension(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_progressBarThickness, strokeWidth);
            progress = typedArray.getFloat(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_my_circle_progress, progress);
            color = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_progressbarColor, color);
            min = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_min, min);
            max = typedArray.getInt(R.styleable.CircleProgressBar_max, max);
        } finally {
            typedArray.recycle();
        }

        backgroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        backgroundPaint.setColor(adjustAlpha(color, 0.3f));
        backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        backgroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

        foregroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        foregroundPaint.setColor(color);
        foregroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        foregroundPaint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawOval(rectF, backgroundPaint);
        float angle = 360 * progress / max;
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, angle, false, foregroundPaint);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        final int height = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
        final int width = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        final int min = Math.min(width, height);
        setMeasuredDimension(min, min);
        rectF.set(0 + strokeWidth / 2, 0 + strokeWidth / 2, min - strokeWidth / 2, min - strokeWidth / 2);
    }

    /**
     * Lighten the given color by the factor
     *
     * @param color  The color to lighten
     * @param factor 0 to 4
     * @return A brighter color
     */
    public int lightenColor(int color, float factor) {
        float r = Color.red(color) * factor;
        float g = Color.green(color) * factor;
        float b = Color.blue(color) * factor;
        int ir = Math.min(255, (int) r);
        int ig = Math.min(255, (int) g);
        int ib = Math.min(255, (int) b);
        int ia = Color.alpha(color);
        return (Color.argb(ia, ir, ig, ib));
    }

    /**
     * Transparent the given color by the factor
     * The more the factor closer to zero the more the color gets transparent
     *
     * @param color  The color to transparent
     * @param factor 1.0f to 0.0f
     * @return int - A transplanted color
     */
    public int adjustAlpha(int color, float factor) {
        int alpha = Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * factor);
        int red = Color.red(color);
        int green = Color.green(color);
        int blue = Color.blue(color);
        return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
    }

    /**
     * Set the progress with an animation.
     * Note that the {@link android.animation.ObjectAnimator} Class automatically set the progress
     * so don't call the {@link CircleProgressBar#setProgress(float)} directly within this method.
     *
     * @param progress The progress it should animate to it.
     */
    public void setProgressWithAnimation(float progress) {
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "progress", progress);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(animDuration);
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(0.8f));
        objectAnimator.start();
    }
```

**res/values/attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CircleProgressBar">
        <attr name="min" format="integer" />
        <attr name="max" format="integer" />
        <attr name="my_circle_progress" format="integer" />
        <attr name="progressbarColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="progressBarThickness" format="dimension" />

    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Взятое [отсюда](https://github.com/Pedramrn/CircularProgressBar)